# Add Secondary to Replica Set in MongoDB Windows

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add the second replica set to primary.

Primary = 192.168.56.52:27017
Secondary = 192.168.56.136:27017

```
    # mongod.conf

    # for documentation of all options, see:
    #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: **mypath**\DBs
      journal:
        enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path:  **mypath**\mongod.log

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0


    #processManagement:

    #security:
    #operationProfiling:

    replication:
      replSetName: configServers

    #sharding:

    ## Enterprise-Only Options:

    #auditLog:

    #snmp:
    #mp:
```

But when I try I add 
rs.add("192.168.56.136:27017")
It shows as picture .
[image: result]
Please help to get run replicaset. Thanks.
I run on windows and start replicaset with service .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error message says, you have added the Primary node of the replica set as `localhost`. The rule is all nodes of the replica set should be localhost or all should be hostname/ip address.

If you run `rs.status()` from primary, you will see the primary replica set member as localhost. So when you try to add a secondary with `rs.add("192.168.56.136:27017")` the system will throw an error.

How to correct this?

conf = rs.conf()

update the hostname of primary member in conf variable

then run

rs.reConfig(conf)

Now add the secondary member.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me a lot.